# ANTLR4 Fragment for parser rules

Tags: scala, antlr, antlr4

Let say I have the following ANTLR4 grammar :

```
grammar test;

call : name=(F | G | H) LPAREN RPAREN

F : 'f';
G : 'g';
H : 'h';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
```

I'm able within the listener to do something like this (scala code):

```
override def exitCall( ctx : testParser.CallContext ) = {
  ctx.name.getType match{
   case testParser.F => //handle F 
   case testParser.G => //handle G 
   case testParser.H => //handle H 
   case _ => 
  }
}
```

But if I want to re-use the alternative `F | G | H` elsewhere, I need to do
either copy and paste it or do something like `alt : (F | G | H);` and I can not any longer match using `getType`. I need to do something like that `if(ctx.name.F() != null)` which is ugly.

Antlr happily compiles

```
  call : name=ALT LPAREN RPAREN
  ALT : F | G | H;
```

But it does not work, I can't even figure out what the parser is expecting. all of `f()`, `ALT()`, `F | G | H()` are failing.

I there a way to have something like fragments but for parser rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for `F|G|H` check for a generic identifier and perform call name validation into `exitCall()`.